# Copy with ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, copy, ng2-dragula

I would like to have my source model to remain unchanged after dragging one element away.
Here is what i have sofar: 
component.ts:

```
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    this.dragulaService.dropModel('DragItems').subscribe(dropItem => {
        this.text += dropItem.item.data;
    });
}
```

component.html:

```html
<ul [dragula]="'DragItems'" [dragulaModel]="datas">
    <li *ngFor="let data of datas">
        <div class="list-item-class">
            {{data.value}}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my target field i already have some text and get the value of the dragged item appended to the end of the existing text, but the dragged item disappears. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use options to [tell Dragula that your item should be copied](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula#copyitem-titem-t--t) and not moved:

> `copyItem: <T>(item: T) => T`
>
> When you have:
>
> - `[(dragulaModel)]`
> - copy is true or *a function that returns true*
>
> ... ng2-dragula will have to create a clone of the JS object you picked
>   up. In previous versions of `ng2-dragula`, there was a terribly buggy,
>   one-size-fits-all clone function. From v2 onwards, you **MUST** provide
>   your own `copyItem` function.
>
> If you have a simple object with no nested values, it could be as
>   simple as:
>   `{   copy: ...,   copyItem: (item: MyType) => ({ ...item }) }`
>
> There is a complete example using a Person class on the [demo page](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The trick was before calling `this.dragulaService.dropModel(...`  i had to set the copy option:

```
this.dragulaService.find('DragItems').options.copy = true;
this.dragulaService.find('DragItems').options.copyItem = (item: any) => ({...item});
```